# Cannot use installed packages with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

**Edit: Adding ~/npm/bin to path with PATH=$PATH:~/npm/bin helped, thank you [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson)**

EDIT:

Seems like i cannot install any packages with npm. After sucessfully installing them, i cannot use them with the assigned commands in the package. "No command '' found".

```
node -v 
v0.11.14

npm -v
2.0.0
```

At ubuntu machine

It seems like i cannot install the resume-cli module, found [here](https://github.com/jsonresume/resume-cli) with using npm. Even though it installs without errors, it does not understand the basic commands after installing. Could it be a problem with the warning, showed under?

```
sudo npm install -g resume-cli
```

i get

```
   npm WARN engine html-to-text@0.0.8: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.32","npm":"1.4.28"})
```

Then

```
/home/bjornasm/npm/bin/resume -> /home/bjornasm/npm/lib/node_modules/resume-cli/index.js
resume-cli@0.3.10 /home/bjornasm/npm/lib/node_modules/resume-cli
├── cli-spinner@0.1.5
├── char-spinner@1.0.1
├── commander@2.3.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── open@0.0.5
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── async@0.9.0
├── read@1.0.5 (mute-stream@0.0.4)
├── terminal-menu@0.3.2 (inherits@2.0.1, charm@0.1.2, resumer@0.0.0)
├── superagent@0.18.2 (extend@1.2.1, qs@0.6.6, methods@1.0.1, cookiejar@2.0.1,  component-emitter@1.1.2, reduce-component@1.0.1, mime@1.2.11, debug@1.0.4, readable-stream@1.0.27-1, form-data@0.1.3, formidable@1.0.14)
├── resume-to-text@0.0.15 (mustache@0.8.2, html-to-text@0.0.8)
├── resume-to-html@0.0.21 (gravatar@1.0.6, resume-to-markdown@0.0.14, marked@0.3.2, mustache@0.8.2, lodash@2.4.1)
├── jsonlint@1.6.2 (nomnom@1.8.0, JSV@4.0.2)   
└── resume-schema@0.0.15 (z-schema@2.4.10)
```

Then when running the following

```
resume --help
```

i get

```
resume: command not found
```

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Do you have `~/npm/bin` in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps to install a given release from source
NOTE - this installs nodejs which gives you both node as well as npm, they come together per release.

to start fresh remove prior node.js and npm installs as well as these :

```
sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore
```

to install nodejs and npm as yourself NOT root do these commands (OSX/linux) :

```
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/bin_0_10_32

mkdir ${NODE_PARENT}
```

download source from :    http://nodejs.org/download/

```
cd node-v0.xxxx

./configure   --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs

make -j8
make install   #  IMPORTANT this is NOT using sudo
               # not wanted since installing into $USER owned $NODE_PARENT
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

```
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

define environment variable NODE_PATH so node can find dir for modules otherwise
npm install xxx will put newly installed module into current dir :

```
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/lib/node_modules
```

when you use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

nodejs install gives you npm as well :

```
ls -la ${NODE_PARENT}/nodejs/bin
```

Subsequent modules you install using global flag -g will automagically put their ~binaries~ into above bin dir ... like browserify

Now put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such so your environment is setup